# How can I map ctrl to space in normal mode?

Tags: vim

I use heavily scrolling commands like Ctrl+E but Ctrl is not easily reachable on my keyboard. Is it possible to replace these with Space so that I can type Space+E to scroll ?
I have tried `nnoremap <Space-e> <C-e>` and `nnoremap <Space> <C>` but it doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, hold `<space>` then press other key cannot be achieved in vim.  what you can think about is, swap ctrl and caplock, to make it easier to reach for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside Vim, only the regular modifier keys <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, and <kbd>Alt</kbd> can be used and combined with other keys. Something like `<Space-e>` doesn't work, cp. `:help key-notation`.

When the Ctrl key is awkward to use, you have to use features of the operating system to switch keys (usually globally for all applications, though some tools like *AutoHotkey* on Windows also support application-specific remappings). With that, the key received by Vim will still be Ctrl, but you've triggered that by pressing a different physical key on your keyboard.

These pages from the Vim Tips Wiki should get you started:

- [Map caps lock to escape in Windows](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Map_caps_lock_to_escape_in_Windows)
- [Map caps lock to escape in XWindows](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Map_caps_lock_to_escape_in_XWindows)